# Scrapy, pyinstaller, and missing modules galore

Tags: python, scrapy, fatal-error, pyinstaller

I'm developing a scrapy program in python 2.7 to scrape data off of nhtsa.gov. It works great in command line, but I want to package it into a single file application so I'm using pyinstaller. Pyinstaller creates an application file, but when run it says "Fatal Error! NHTSAscrape returned -1". When I go into the warning log file, there are like a hundred missing modules, modules that I've never even heard of:

```
missing module named posix - imported by os
missing module named codecs.mbcs_encode - imported by codecs, encodings.mbcs
missing module named codecs.mbcs_decode - imported by codecs, encodings.mbcs
missing module named datetime.date - imported by datetime, _strptime,
missing module named 'six.moves.urllib' - imported by 'six.moves.urllib', 
missing module named _xmlrpclib - imported by xmlrpclib, 
missing module named twisted.version - imported by twisted, scrapy, 
missing module named cStringIO.InputType - imported by cStringIO, twisted.python.compat, twisted.persisted.styles
missing module named cStringIO.OutputType - imported by cStringIO, twisted.python.compat, twisted.persisted.styles
missing module named 'urllib.parse' - imported by twisted.python.compat, lxml.html, twisted.web.http
```

...and many more. I am now running my spec file to create the application, and trying to edit the "hiddenimports" and "excludes" fields, but this doesn't really change anything. For instance, if I say

```
 excludes=['posix','codecs','codecs.mbcs_encode']
```

The warning log file gives the same as above, but adds "excluded module posix" etc, but it doesn't seem to actually exclude the module.

There must be an easier way to take care of all of these missing modules, or some reason that all of these modules are being referenced even though my program doesn't use them.

I can post the full log file if anyone is interested. Thoughts?

Comment: The list includes 'urllib.parse', which is part of Python 3. It looks like PyInstaller may be trying to find modules by some static parsing of the source files. So I don’t think the missing module warnings are a problem, those things are not needed in Python 2.

Comment: Have you tried adding debug calls to your code, to try and find out exactly at which point of execution things fail? Can you provide a very basic example to reproduce the issue? How have you managed to package the scrapy configuration files and such into the executable and have the eecutable run scrapy from the proper working directory?